# Web API Entity Framework Returning linked table

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, webapi

So I have two Database Tables
Club
 - ClubId
 - ClubName

ClubMembers

- ClubMemberId
- ClubId
- FirstName
- LastName

in my api controller I have

```
private ClubsEntities db = new ClubsEntities();

        // GET: api/Clubs
        public IQueryable<Club> GetClub()
        {
            return db.Club;

        }
```

But when I hit it i get data returned from both tables

```
[{"ClubMember":[{"ClubMemberId":1,"ClubId":1,"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Smith"}],"ClubId":1,"ClubName":"Test"},{"ClubMember":[],"ClubId":2,"ClubName":"Test 2"}]
```

How can I get it to just return from club this is baffling me

Comment: I believe there is a flag on the `DbContext` that you can set that will disable this unless specifically requested. I believe the flag is `LazyLoadingEnabled` -- [here's a quick reference](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so ive figured out that if I just specify a new class just with the values I want returned and select those values, it will keep my returned data cleaner.

```
return db.Club.Select(c => new myClubs { ClubId = c.ClubId, ClubName = c.ClubName }).ToList();
```